# como leer tr de una tabla que se lee de un cliclo for

Tags: html, python, tr

Hola estoy intentando crear una tabla de los días dependiendo dos fechas, que me los represente en dias y por semanas,ya lo logre hacer el problema es que al leer los días creados en un areglo, esos datos los mostare en una tabla el problema esta que los tr me los lee de forma vertical y no horizontal, lo estoy realizando en python.

Mi areglo de dias:

```
Dias = ['L','M','M','J','V','S','D']
```

mi html

```
<table class="tabla2">
            {%for fecha in fechas %}
              
               {%if(fecha.strftime('%a') == 'lun.'):%}
                    {%for dia in dias%}
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{dia}}</td>
                      </tr>
                      
                    {%endfor%}
               {%endif%}
               {%if(fecha.strftime('%a') != 'lun.'):%}
                   {%if fecha.day == inicio.day:%}
                        {%for dia in dias%}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{dia}}</td>
                          </tr>
                        {%endfor%}
                   {%endif%}
               {%endif%}
               
               
            {%endfor%}
            
        </table>
```

me sale si no incluyo los tr, pero no es la forma correcta, por que debajo de los días voy a llenar los días con un color dependiendo la fecha